# Gujarati lang support in pdfCalligraph addon with iText

Tags: java, itext, itext7

When using iText and pdfCalligraph addon (trial license), the Indic language :

**Gujarati text** :

```
ઉદ્ધવ  [Unicode - %u0A89%u0AA6%u0ACD%u0AA7%u0AB5]
```

is being rendered differently as [image depicting word in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WiaT.png)

Is there any other code/configuration required to get this right?
Given below is the function used. html2pdf is the open-source library used, that uses iText internally.

```java
private static void pdfConverter() {
    File htmlSource = new File("src/main/resources/certificate/index.html");
    File pdfDest = new File("output.pdf");
    try {
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        DefaultFontProvider defaultFontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, true, true);
        defaultFontProvider.addDirectory("src/main/resources/fonts");
        converterProperties.setFontProvider(defaultFontProvider);
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlSource, pdfDest, converterProperties);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, with your 30 day trial you can also contact iText Software directly for such technical questions.

Answer (score 0):

which fonts are you using? This is the output I get using [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfhtml) 2.1.5 + [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph) 2.0.5-SNAPSHOT.

[image]

Can you also try changing your code to:

```
DefaultFontProvider defaultFontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
```

you probably have other fonts getting picked up to be used to render your text, and with this constructor, you'll use the ones you are specifying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can pull down 2.0.4 com.itextpdf.typography from maven and can't 2.0.5-SNAPSHOT. Anyway to get it?
The font file - NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf is part of src/main/resources directory.

Comment: with version 2.0.4, I get the same behavior. Can you change the DefaultFontProvider constructor, and point directly to the ttf file (something like fontProvider.addFont(FontProgramFactory.createFont("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf"));

Comment: I can, but am not always sure what kind of language is going to be there. Are you doubting that adding directory of fonts maybe a problem and recommending to add them file by file?

Comment: no, just trying to get to the bottom of the problem. Have you tried changing the constructor arguments as suggested?